# data in one matrix automatically getting copied to another matrix in opencv in c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, matrix

I have made one function in which I am passing a matrix and returning processed matrix, but the data of processed matrix is getting copied into the matrix which I passed, for ex.

```
    output=processMatrix(srcCopy);
```

then when I show both of these matrix, I get same image in srcCopy and output also, I am allocating them memory as;

```
    output=Mat(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1 );
    srcCopy=Mat(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1 );
```

Comment: can you show the declaration and code of the `processMatrix` function?

Comment: `cv::Mat skeletonize(cv::Mat);`

Comment: in processMatrix() I am releasing the matrix which I am passing from main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `cv::Mat` copy constructor does a *shallow copy* of the source `cv::Mat`. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat). What you probably need to do is use the `cv::MAt::clone()` method to create a clone of the original. Then, you can avoid the shallow copy in the function parameter list:

```
cv::Mat skeletonize(const cv::Mat& m) { 
  // use clone() in here to make a new Mat and return it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Mat Mat::clone()` to create a copy.

```
Mat dst= src.clone();
src.Release();
```

documentation of [Mat Clone](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone)